# What is the difference between primrec and fun in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle

I'm reading the Isabelle tutorial and been trying to clear my concept on use of primrec and fun. With what I've searched so far, including the answer [here](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/htdig/cl-isabelle-users/2012-August/msg00042.html); I understand  that constructor inside primrec can have only one equation and primrec has [simp] by default whereas fun can have multiple equations and the automation tactics need to be specified explicitly. However, I still struggle to understand it clearly.

Anyone kind enough to explain with some examples?

Comment: Too lazy to cook up examples, so this is just a comment: From a practitioner’s point of view, `primrec` is a lower-level tool that you usually do not need to worry about, and simply always use `fun`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`primrec` does [primitive recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) on an algebraic datatype (or something that has been set up to look like one, like the natural numbers; I don't know much about the internals of it). This means that you have a lot of restrictions in the kind of recursion schemes that you can have:

- You can only have exactly one non-variable argument on the left-hand side (i.e. only one parameter on which you can do pattern matching). You cannot do something like `f (x#xs) (y#ys) = …` or `f n = (if n = 0 then … else …)`.
- You can only pattern match on a single constructor (i.e. `x # xs`, but not `x # y # xs`)
- You can only call the function recursively on exactly the variables that you matched on the left-hand side, i.e. `f (Node l r) = … f l … f r …`, but not `f (Node l r) = … f (Node r l) …`.
- Nested recursion is only possible if it mirrors the definition of the datatype.

`fun` comes from the function package and is a simplified version of `function` that tries to prove exhaustiveness, non-overlappedness of patterns, and termination automatically. This works for most functions that arise in practice; when it does not, one has to use `function` and prove these things by hand. Termination is usually the one tricky one.

The main difference between `fun` and `primrec` is that `fun` has none of the restrictions I listed above for `primrec`. With `fun`, pretty much everything goes. As far as I know, everything `primrec` can do, `fun` can do as well.

`function` can also do a lot of other things such as mutually-recursive functions, partial functions (i.e. functions that do not terminate on all inputs), conditional function equations, etc. Refer to the [function package manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/functions.pdf) for more information on this.

Another feature of the `function` command is that it generates a number of helpful rules for each function defined with it, such as the `cases` rule, the `induction` rule, the `elims` rules, etc. Also, you can automatically derive specialised elimination rules with the `fun_cases` command. This, too, is described in the manual.

TL;DR: what Joachim said. `fun` is usually what you want to use. If it is not enough, use `function`. You can use `primrec` for very simple functions, but there is no real advantage to do so. Another alternative that may be interesting for possibly non-terminating functions is `inductive`.

Comment: Minor correction: `fun` also supports mutual recursion, not only `function`.

Comment: Oh, indeed it does. TIL.

Comment: For algebraic datatypes without a `size` function (e.g., infinitely branching trees), `primrec` is superior to `fun`, because the automated termination proof methods (which `fun` calls internally) require `size` functions. In that case, you have to do a manual termination proof, which can be rather tedious.